# Matlab - Double duration of .wav

Tags: matlab, double

I'm creating individual notes from a single note thats read in using the `wavread` function.

I'm using the `resample` function to create these notes. eg:

```
    f5  = resample(a,440,698); %creates note.
    f5_short  = f5(dur:Hz);    %creates duration of note (ie 1 sec)
    f5_hf  = f5_short(dur:Hz/2); %creates note of half duration
```

The above code seems to work well. Unfortunately i'm having trouble creating a "double note"... I don't want to just play the same note twice and i've tried the following:

```
    f5_db  = f5_short(dur*2:Hz); %exceeds size of matrix
    f5_db  = f5_short(dur:Hz*2); %exceeds size of matrix
    f5_db  = resample(f5_short,Hz*2,330); %tried upSampling it and although lengths it, note becomes deeper.
```

Whats the easiest why to double the length of a not/wav without changing the note? (stretch but maintain the correct note?) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double the size of `f5_short`, not to index it:

```
f5_db = repmat(f5_short, 2, 1);
```

or just

```
f5_db = [f5_short; f5_short];
```

---

If you have pause in the beginning and in the end of `f5_short`, but the middle sequence is constant, you can reproduce the middle to get double note. Something like this:

```
f5_short_len = length(f5_short);
f5_short_mid = floor(f5_short_len/2);
f5_db = [f5_short(1:f5_short_mid,:); ...
         repmat(f5_short(f5_short_mid,:),f5_short_len,1); ...
         f5_short(f5_short_mid+1:f5_short_len,:)];
```

If you want to remove the pauses;

```
f5_short = repmat(f5_short(f5_short_mid),f5_short_len,1);
f5_db = repmat(f5_short, 2, 1);
```

Comment: I've tried the `repmat` method but it throws an error when you concatenate it, eg `sample = [f5_db; d4_short];`. And using your second method isn't beneficial as there is a slight pause before and after the original notes so you get a pause inside the lengthen note...

Comment: Are you sure you have to concatenate vertically with `;` symbol? If they have different length, you will get error. Try `,` to concatenate horizontally. What is `a` in your first expression? Can you give an example to generate it?

Comment: Ah, you are using Signal Processing Toolbox. Don't have it. But if you have a pause in the beginning and the end of sequence, you probably can multiply some sequence from the middle. What is `f5_short` size?

Comment: I read the wav file in and resample it `f5 = resample(a,440,698);` a is a piano note of a4 hence the 440Hz in the resample... The f5_short is 1 second long, generated by `f5_short = f5(1:44100);`

Comment: I mean what exactly does `size(f5_short)` return? What `class(f5_short)` returns? Can you detect where the beginning pause stops and end pause starts? At what time you have a constant sequence?

Comment: size(f5_short) returns `44100   1` and class(f5_short) returns `double`... If I plot(f5_short), it has about 3000milliseconds of no sound either side, the middle (the note) is constant

Comment: I updated the answer. There might be some functions in the toolbox, but this way is strait-forward.